# How can I dynamically generate a PrivateRoute redirect based on an axios response?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-router, axios

I have an endpoint in my app called `/get-redirect`, which basically redirects you to wherever you need to be.

E.g. if you're not logged in, the response from this endpoint is an HTTP 200 with the `redirect_location` field in the response set to `mysite.com/login`. If you're logged in, but haven't completed step 2 of onboarding, it sends an HTTP 200 with `redirect_location` set to `mysite.com/step2`, etc.

I want to use `PrivateRoute` in React Router for authenticated pages, and I want any redirects to go to the result of the `/get-redirect` endpoint. I would then render the appropriate component in the  statement.

This is what I have so far but I keep getting that the `getPage()` function is returning undefined. What am I missing here?

```js
const fakeAuth = {
  getPage(cb) {
    if (document.cookie === null) {
      return '/login'
    }

    const url = "https://api.mysite.com/get-redirect"

    axios.get(url)
    .then(function (response) {
      return response.redirect_location
    }).catch(function (error) {
        if (error.response.status === 401) {
          return '/401'
        }
        return '/404'
    })
  },
}


function PrivateRoute({ children, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <Route {...rest} render={() => {
      return <Redirect to={{
        pathname: fakeAuth.getPage()
      }} />
    }} />
  )
}


class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          ...
          <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard">
            <Dashboard />
          </PrivateRoute>

          ....
```

Comment: (1) `getPage` needs to return the Promise chain started by `axios`, and (2) you'll need to wait for this in `PrivateRoute` so you can't just set it as the redirect path and immediately return.

Comment: Is there a design pattern you could show me so I could implement this? How would you go about doing this?

Comment: @DrewReese What if the `redirect_location` is the same as the PrivateRoute path? How do I avoid an infinite loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

1. `getPage` needs to return the Promise chain started by `axios`.
2. You will need to wait for the Promise to resolve (or reject) in the `PrivateRoute` component but you can't just return the result as the redirect target.

## Solution

I suggest abstracting a component to do the endpoint check and conditionally render the redirect or the original `children` prop. While the endpoint is checked conditionally render some loading state or null until the expected result is returned then conditionally render the redirect or child `Dashboard` component.

Example

```
const CheckRedirect = ({ children }) => {
  const [isChecking, setIsChecking] = React.useState(true);
  const [target, setTarget] = React.useState("/");

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fakeAuth
      .getPage()
      .then((target) => {
        setTarget(target);
      })
      .finally(() => setIsChecking(false));
  }, []);

  if (isChecking) return "...Checking"; // or loading spinner, or null

  return target.redirect_location ? (
    <Redirect to={target.redirect_location} />
  ) : (
    children
  );
};

function PrivateRoute({ children, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <Route {...rest} render={() => <CheckRedirect children={children} />} />
  );
}
```

## Demo

[image: Edit how-can-i-dynamically-generate-a-privateroute-redirect-based-on-an-axios-respons]

For demo this is the mocked auth `getPage` component, it has a 50% chance to return redirect target.

```
const fakeAuth = {
  getPage(cb) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        return resolve(
          Math.random() < 0.5 ? { redirect_location: "/step2" } : {}
        );
      }, 3000);
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you. Regarding the `getPage` you mocked up: I see you hard-coded the redirect_location. Do you know what returning a promise (specifically, the result of an axios command) to dynamically populate that field would look like?

Comment: Also, I actually don't think this accomplishes the goal. Specifically, in the return switch statement in CheckRedirect. 
My understanding is we *never* want to render the child component by way of a simple "render the child of the PrivateRoute if authenticated". We always want to render it by way of a redirect from the get-redirect endpoint. Does that make sense?

Comment: The purpose of the <PrivateRoute> isn't to check if the user is authenticated before rendering the child component. It's really just to designate certain pages as "off limits", unless you are explicitly redirected to them by the `get-redirect` endpoint. Knowing that, how would this answer change?

Comment: Yeah, I confirmed I was right. I have an infinite loop now, because the redirect sends it right back to the `<PrivateRoute>`. Any suggestions?

Comment: @AlwaysQuestioning I see. Typically a `PrivateRoute` component simply checks if the user is authenticated... if they are, render the component for *that* path, otherwise you bounce them to *some* login route. I assumed this was the case since your `PrivateRoute` is rendering a `Dashboard` component but it sounds like you simply want your `PrivateRoute` to always redirect elsewhere, the result of the `get-redirect` endpoint. In this case you can return `null` instead of `children` and move the `Dashboard` (*or whatever*) component to the target path. How do you protect *that* route though?

Comment: Yeah, so that page will also be behind PrivateRoute
I just need a stateful way to say "if this redirect was the result of a response from the `/get-redirect`endpoint, then don't call out to that endpoint again!"

Comment: So if someone tries to go to `/account`, which is behind a `PrivateRoute`, but the endpoint says "No, you haven't linked your bank account yet!' and redirects them to `/bank-account`, which *itself* is behind a `<PrivateRoute>`... we have an infinite loop!

Comment: @AlwaysQuestioning Ah, so in addition to landing on a private route and *possibly* doing the auth check you could send some route state to the redirect target path that says they landed on a private route via a redirect so don't do the auth check again?

Comment: Exactly right! I'm having trouble with that part

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231865/discussion-between-alwaysquestioning-and-drew-reese).

Comment: @AlwaysQuestioning Please check chat when you have time.